# How to format a String from "2" to "02" in c

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define VERSION "2.16.0.0"

int main ()
{
//char buf[] ="2.16.0.0";
int i = 0;
int j ;

char letter[8];

//char a[] = VERSION;

for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
     letter[i] = VERSION[i];
}
char *array;
char* copy = letter ;
 while ((array = strtok_r(copy, ".", &copy)))
     printf("%s\n", array);

        printf("%s", array);
}
```

I split the macro to 2 16 0 0.

Now, I want to format it to 02 16 00 00. How do I do it?
I tried using sprintf() function to format the array but that didn't work out, any other way?

Comment: Your `VERSION` string take 9 characters. You do not copy the terminating 0 byte into `letter`. That means, you don't pass a valid string to `strtok` causing undefined behaviour. You could create your array just by doing `char letter[] = VERSION;`

Comment: Since the parts of the version string are still strings, you cannot use the "leading zeroes" formatting modifiers commonly used for numbers. So you need to retrieve the length of each string and prepend it with enough zeroes. Think how you would tell it to your kid, and then implement that in source.

Comment: @thebusybee With MSVC like this: `printf("%02s", array);` is that non-standard?

Comment: @WeatherVane To my understanding, it is non-standard. the `0` flag only has defined behavior for integer and floating-point fields. However, since OP is actually printing integers, we can print with `%02d` which is standard. See my answer below.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, it is non-standard. For example Clang prints a warning due to undefined behavior, but the Windows executable works as assumed; probably it uses MS's implementation. Anyway, the OP seems to target an embedded system, which compiler we don't know. (But I don't trust the tag. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your program can be simplified in several ways (see below) and I have to point out at least one significant error since the copy of the string in `letter` does not include the terminating 0.

About how to print, as I understand you would like to print the numerical entries with 2 digits. One method to do that is to convert them to integers and format the output using the `printf` formatting options:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define VERSION "2.16.0.0"

int main ()
{
    char *element;
    char copy[] = VERSION;
    element = strtok(copy, ".");
    while (element != NULL)
    {
        printf("%02d ", atoi(element));
        element = strtok(NULL, ".");
    }
}
```